# Windows Powershell and Command Prompt windows shrink when commands are used

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I'm not sure what causes it to shrink this way. Here are some things that make it shrink:

- npx install
- flutter doctor

things that don't:

- cding, other folder actions
- launching editors like python or node

Here's what it looks like in fullscreen:

[image: in fullscreen]

it automatically shrinks the window when I'm not in fullscreen like this:

[image: this]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will be caused by the window buffer size settings.

Please try the following:

```
Right click the window title bar & click "Defaults" then click ok on the window that pops up.
```

If you still have issues:

```
Right click the window title bar & Click Properties.

Navigate to "Layout" tab.

Change the "Screen Buffer Size" Height to 70 (Change this if text goes off the bottom of the window.)

Check the box "Wrap text output on resize".
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. **open Regedit**

   •press win+r and type regedit -> press enter
   •approve admin permission
2. **in regedit browse to: "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"**

   •Under " there is an AutoRun key, back it up (click file > export)

3.**Delete the AutoRun key**

4.**Try opening CMD again**

if it works, i recommend you edit the default properties to your preference